# Meaningless counterfactuals

Tags: logic

What is the term for believing that counterfactual statements do not have definite truth values? i.e., that the only possible world is the actual world.

Also are there any philosophers known for that belief?

Comment: Error theorist? Not specific to counterfactual (it can apply to laws of nature, morality...).

Comment: See also actualism http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/

Comment: Your 'i.e.' doesn't follow, one can accept that counterfactuals do not have truth values without believing that the only possible world is the actual world.

Comment: Can counter-factual worlds have *indefinite* truth-values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mario Bunge (1977) made an ontological theory in which he proves there is just one world. In his book: Ontology I: The furniture of the world. pp. 34, theorem 1.5.